# How to utilize the free time during office hours?

Tags: career-development, productivity, time-management

I am a software developer and most of the times when I find free time I read few news or technical websites like Techcrunch, Gizmodo, etc or read Twitter. How do I utilize this time to the maximum, instead of wasting on browsing unnecessary things so that it will help me grow professionally?

Comment: We learn by doing, not be reading. Find a project that has relevance and do it. The most common project people seem to take on that has meaning in just about every endeavor is the building a content management system.

Comment: [Relevant link](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/937/2322).

Comment: Could you point me to where I can get some of this "free time" of which you speak? It seems that my company does not have that item in the supply closet.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is identify a technology that I'm interested in and then research it in my brief (and rare) moments of free time.  For instance, there may be a new technology or framework that I've been hearing about and I think it'll become useful to me in the future.  What I do is get a book (an ebook usually) and then read up on it.

For me, a key is to stick with one subject until I'm ready to move on. I'm rather ADD and keeping things to a single subject helps me maximize the time I spend as well as my typically limited attention span.

I try to keep the subject matter limited to technologies that I can pick up and put down at a moment's notice without having to get myself into a mode of deep thought.  For example, some hot new javascript framework versus quantum physics.  :)

I do try to keep my searching for new topics off of work machines because I don't want to be perceived as "that guy" who is always browsing, even if the searching is technology related and worthy of my time.

Comment: Great inputs :) thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

You also might want to take one of those breaks and walk outside or even around the office for a few minutes. Giving your mind and eyes a rest from a computer can do wonders and allow you to focus better on your work. Doing focused research like @ChristopherEstep suggested is also a great idea.

Comment: plus it prevents bad wonders, like depressions (esp. for introvert ppl), muscle lost and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I will usually read books. In my down time I am reading "Effective Java" to improve my Java skills and "Code Complete 2nd Edition" to become a better engineer.